# for loop continues to run even when "break" is used

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to run a check within a folder that will display only one alert if there is any other file than extension - '.txt'

Here is my code:

```
for (let file of files) {
  const ext = path.extname(file);
  console.log(typeof file)
  if (ext != '.txt') {
    console.log(ext)
    console.log("The error should have popped up")
    dialog.showErrorBox('Non TXT file detected', 'there is a non-txt file in the folder')
    break
  }
  else {
    console.log("Not Working")
  }
}
```

The issue that I am having is that say there were 10 ".txt" files in the folder, if I renamed one of them to ".test" I would receive 10 alerts. Is there a way to as soon as the "dialog.showErrorBox" has been called prevent to for loop for continuing.

I receive the same amount of errors no matter which file i change the extension for.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on automatic semicolon insertion (ASI): [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on people telling you not to rely on automatic semicolon insertion (ASI): [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Comment: Even though Im not entirely sure about this, I think its better (and correct..?) to use `!==` instead of `!=`. Maybe that causes your problem :)

Comment: I've made a simplified version of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/tw7p31dv, your code seems to be working. Can you check your files again

Comment: `break` definitely ends the `for..of` loop, are you re-running the loop later? With the current code you should get only a single error, no matter how many filenames having a different extension.

Comment: How is `files` value collected?

Comment: In response - Teemu, I am not running the loop again later. Petar - I have tried with both and still receive the issue. raina77ow - I am using fs.readdir

Comment: If you run mxdi9i7's fiddle (or [mine](https://jsfiddle.net/gvswt7x0/)), you can see only a single error message, and `break` works as expected.

Comment: Please add the reading code. Do you see 9 '.txt' and one '.test' entries in the log?

Answer (score -1):

I replicated your code, and it seems to work fine: https://repl.it/repls/ExcellentVapidApplicationframework

Maybe an issue caused by ASI, as Andreas suggested?

Comment: There is nothing problematic with lacking semicolons in the provided code.